# Downloading multiple resource files simultaneously in Android applications

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, download

In my Android application I have an requirement to download multiple files from the server simultaneously and update progress each of them individually like we are doing in browser or any download manager.

So I would like to know is there any best approach to follow like for single resource we can follow async task to download.

Let me know if any example or sample code or suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: see android.app.DownloadManager

Comment: DownloadManager works well for such things, also would it make sense to zip multiple files first and then download as a single item? This assumes that you have control of the server and files to do such a thing and that it fits your usage model.

Comment: Yes I have seen its really good to implement but can we track the progress of each file and update our custom progress bar based on that so is there any method available to get progress data of each file

Comment: You can wrap downloading files with `AsyncTask` (and execute an instance of it for each download) and update progress on UI by implementing `onProgressChanged`

Comment: I have implemented Download Manager just I need the progress of each file that can complete my task